# check elasticsearch connection status in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect elasticsearch in my local and I wonder how can I know the connection is successful or failed before continue to process:
I wish it is possible with the way below I used but not(it returns too many values but all useless):

```
try:
    es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200/'], verify_certs=True)
except Exception as err:
    if "Connection refused" in err.message:
        logging.error("Connection failed")
```

I hope there is a way to check connection status like this:

```
if es == false:
    raise ValueError("Connection failed")
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

What you can do is call [`ping`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.ping) after creating the `Elasticsearch` instance, like this:

```
es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200/'], verify_certs=True)

if not es.ping():
    raise ValueError("Connection failed")
```

Comment: I know its old post, but currently even I am looking for answer to the same question, but the problem with your answer is that when elasticsearch service is down es.ping() doesn't return False but returns the error

Comment: You can still wrap the call to es.ping within a try/catch block (like in the original question) and that would do the job as well.

Comment: The thing is the exceptions raised are chained. I mean the final exception raised is ConnectionError but it also raises NewConnectionError and ConnectionRefusedError before that, so which one should be handled. Because it still prints the stack trace of exception

Comment: Any error that hints that a ping could not even be made. So basically any connection errors

Comment: not working  `    raise BadStatusLine(line)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('This is not a HTTP port',))`

Answer (score 1):

I had same `urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError` issue, so made up for myself.

```
import requests
def isRunning(self):
    try:
        res = requests.get("http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health")
        if res.status_code == 200:
            if res.json()['number_of_nodes'] > 0:
                return True
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
```