# Python elastic client search object returns nothing, not even empty response data

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, indexing, error-handling

I am doing an elastic client search operation from an elastic datalake which is configured correctly, I double checked the configuration (esDatalake) and I am getting a response from the esDatalake for the first query in my program, so esDatalake works. However when I run another query with a different search_index and search_query later in the code, my code just stops, No Exceptions caught, No errors found, no empty response data found. Why does this happen?

```
try:
    print("before datalake search")
    widget_data = esDatalake.search(index=search_index, body=widget_query) 
    print("After datalake search")
    if any(error_string in widget_data for error_string in ["error", "Error", "ERROR", "TransportError"]):
        self.logger("Error") 
        raise Exception(f"Elasticsearch error:")
    print(f"widget data is {widget_data}")
    if widget_data: widget_data = widget_data["hits"]["hits"]
    if not widget_data or widget_data == None:
        raise Exception(f"Empty widget data for {widget_id}")
    self.logger.info(f"Data fetched from datalake for {widget_id}")
except Exception as e:
    self.logger.error(f"Could not fetch widget data from {search_index} due to {str(e)}")
    continue # move on to next widget
```

here "before datalake search" is getting printed but not "After datalake search"

double checked search_index and widget_query, tried the same in kibana dev tools and got result as an empty response message where ["hits"]["hits"] is an empty list []. but with this python code, we are not even getting an empty response message saying ["hits"]["hits"] is an empty list []. why?

Comment: When I run this individually with the same query and index I got the empty response message {'took': 2318, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 126, 'successful': 126, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}} -- but when I run the same inside my main program I face the above mentioned issue.

Comment: can you pls share the code where you are establishing the ES connection. As a best practice, you can call ping() as explained in this thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208136/check-elasticsearch-connection-status-in-python

Also recommend moving the None check for widget_data after the search() call, to see if any exceptions are thrown. 
Also you can check for ['hits']['total']['value'] > 0 before checking the ['hits']['hits'] for results.